# possible typo in a math books

Tags: calculus

[image]

I think this is a typo. How come? We know $e^C e^{x^3/3} > 0 $ so $|y| > 0 $ thus $|y| = y $. No?

Comment: The context isn't clear. Anyway, $|y| > 0$ doesn't imply $|y|=y$.

Comment: Since this is presumably a basic diff eq, you should manually check that the case of a negative sign is a valid solution.

Comment: $|y| >0$ doesn't really imply anything, it's always true

Comment: @SpineFeast $|0|=0$.

Comment: up to a set of measure 0*

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of a number is always positive (or at least zero), ie for both $y_1=2$ and $y_2=-2$ we have $|y_1|=|y_2|=2$.

Conversely, $|y|=1$ means $y=\pm 1$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.. $|-2| = 2$. So even if $2 > 0$ and $|-2 |>0$, it doesn't mean that $-2 = |-2|>0$

Answer (score 0):

For any real number $y$, $|y|\geq 0$. All  $|y|>0$ tells you is that $y\neq 0$.